# Load Bootstrap-Multiselect based on optgroup using jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using [Bootstrap-select](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select) like bellow:

```
 <label for="name">CARS</label>
    <select multiple title="Cars" class="selectpicker cars" id="cars">
      <optgroup label="Car">
        <option>Benz</option>
        <option>BMW</option>
        <option>Volvo</option>
        <option>Hyundai</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Bike">
        <option>Benz</option>
        <option>BMW</option>
        <option>Volvo</option>
        <option>Hyundai</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Bicycle">
        <option>Benz</option>
        <option>BMW</option>
        <option>Volvo</option>
        <option>Hyundai</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
```

And I want to load it (select options) based on the Ajax call. I know how to use Ajax call but I don't know how to populate multiselect (select options) based on optgroup. because as you see it has the same options in different optgropus.

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).on('click', '.ModalButton', function(ev){ 
    ev.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).data("form"); 
    var company_name = $(this).data('target');
    $(".Modal").unbind().load(url, function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/app/edit/",
            data: {
                company_name: company_name,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
            },
            success: function(data) {
                <<<<<< Multiselect Populating Code should be placed here >>>>>>>>
            }
        });
        $(this).modal('show');
    });
    return false;
});
```

The Ajax response will be:

```
Car: Benz, Car: BMW, Bike: Benz, Bicycle: Volvo
```

Comment: To your Update: Is the ajax response a pure string or is it a json response? Could you be a little more specific there?

Comment: It is a json response

Answer (score 0):

**SNIPPET FOR YOUR QUESTION**

After your last comment with important details you just have to use this function on `success`

```
// ...
success: function (data) {
  var html = '';
  var target = $('#cars');

  // data has to be in this format for the following loop:
  // '{"Car":["Benz","BMW"],"Bike":["Benz"],"Bicycle":["Volvo"]}'

  $.each(data, function(optGroup, elements) {
    html += '<optgroup label="' + optGroup + '">';

    $.each(elements, function(index, element) {
      html += '<option value="">' + element + '</option>';
    });

    html += '</optgroup>';
  });

  target.html(html);
}
// ...
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

I have build a working example of this snippet below

```js
// you said that the data of your success method is json parsed, so you do not neet do parse the data again in your script
setTimeout(function() {
  successMethod(
    JSON.parse('{"Car":["Benz","BMW"],"Bike":["Benz"],"Bicycle":["Volvo"]}')
  );
  // just set 3 seconds for testing
}, 3000)

function successMethod(data) {
  var html = '';
  var target = $('#cars');

  // data has to be in this format for the following loop:
  // '{"Car":["Benz","BMW"],"Bike":["Benz"],"Bicycle":["Volvo"]}'

  $.each(data, function(optGroup, elements) {
    html += '<optgroup label="' + optGroup + '">';

    $.each(elements, function(index, element) {
      html += '<option value="">' + element + '</option>';
    });

    html += '</optgroup>';
  });
  
  target.html(html);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<label for="name">CARS</label>
<select multiple title="Cars" class="custom-select" id="cars">
  <optgroup label="Car">
    <option>Benz</option>
    <option>BMW</option>
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option>Hyundai</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Bike">
    <option>Benz</option>
    <option>BMW</option>
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option>Hyundai</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Bicycle">
    <option>Benz</option>
    <option>BMW</option>
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option>Hyundai</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: The multiselect is already there, script should just select approperiate options based on ajax call success.

Comment: @Mahdi Yes, you just have to use the `$('.selectpicker').multiselect('rebuild');` method which I have used in this example. Please show us your current code so that we can help you better.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I checked your code but I got the error: Uncaught TypeError: target.multiselect is not a function

Comment: @Mahdi For this case you have not included the bootstrap-multiselect jquery script. The code snippet in my answer seems to work with the bootstrap-multiselect you have linked in your question.

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately, it is my mistake. I'm using Bootstrap-Select not bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: @Mahdi So please update your question with real data. Nobody could help you if you share wrong informations. Do you use the normal `select` tag with just the `multiple` attribute?

Comment: with multiple attribute

Comment: @Mahdi I've made an update of my answer and hope it will help you. Please correct your question.